# Goodness of fit --$\chi^2$ Statistics

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have an elementary question about $\chi^2$ statistic.  Let us say that an experiment
makes a set of measurements $E_i \pm \delta_i$, with $i=1, \ldots, n$. $\delta_i$ are the
uncertainties in experimental measurements. Let us assume that a theory predicts  the values to be $T_i$, again with $i=1, \ldots, n$.  We need to determine if the theory is a good fit for the experimental data.

Does one regard the $E_i-T_i \sim N(0, \delta_i^2)$?  That is, are the errors $E_i-T_i$ assumed to be normally distributed with variance $\delta_i^2$? If the answer is yes, then assuming that the errors are independent, we can take $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(E_i-T_i)^2}{\delta_i^2}$
to be a $\chi^2$ random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom.  My question is,
what is the justification for taking $\delta_i$ to be the estimator of $\sigma_i$, the actual standard deviation of the error variable $E_i-T_i$?

Independently, what is the widely used method for gauging the goodness of fit in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

There is, of course, no way to say for certain that the $E_i - T_i$ are normally distributed (they could theoretically obey any probability distribution, subject to the experimental setup and underlying theory). However, due to the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and many uncontrolled random fluctuations present in any given measurement, it is often a very good approximation to treat them as normally distributed.

With this concession, then yes you are correct. You may treat $\sum_{i=1}^n (E_i-T_i)^2/\delta_i^2$ to be a $\chi^2$ random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom. But note that the $\chi^2$ distribution is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) as the sum of $n$ statistically independent normalized Gaussians, so additionally you must make sure your measurements $E_i$ are independent from one another. Of course, you must also ensure 0 systematic error for your measurements.

One potentially relevant empirical fact that is worth noting is that in nature, distributions tend to have larger tails than predicted by treating everything as a Gaussian. That is, the probability of outliers is higher than predicted by the Central Limit Theorem. Specifically, distributions tend to be closer to [log-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

But again, note that basically all of statistics operates under the assumption that everything is a Gaussian, so don't get too worried about such technicalities.

As for a standard way to measure the goodness of fit, either the goodness of fit parameter Q (discussed in my reference below; it's probably on Wikipedia somewhere but I couldn't easily find it), or the $\chi^2$ per degree of freedom are reasonable metrics.

I learned all of this from [Everything you wanted to know about Data Analysis and Fitting but were afraid to ask](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3781), by Peter Young. It's admittedly slightly skewed toward techniques in Lattice QCD (namely bootstrap and jackknife), but it also answers all the questions you had above in a pedagogical manner.

Comment: If $\delta_i$ is taken to be the estimator of $\sigma_i$, what is the justification?

Comment: The best $\delta_i$ can be is unbiased, which means that if we were to repeat the experiment over and over, the mean value of $\delta_i$ will be equal to $\sigma_i$, the true variance. This will be the case, as long as $\delta_i$ is computed as the sample variance; that is, as long as you compute the variance by dividing by $N-1$ instead of $N$. All this is proved in my reference.

Comment: +1 but I don't follow the bit about log normal distributions representing pseudo-normal distributions with more outliers. I would have thought (and have used) Student's t distributions with low numbers of degree of freedom.